# Change mouse cursor just when mouse is top of line or inside of closed path in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, system.drawing

I want to set event property or change mouse cursor when hover a line, created by Graphics class.

I can set this property for a panel, that contain line, but I want to change mouse cursor just when mouse is top of line.

Comment: Use [GraphicsPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath)s as containers for your shapes and test [IsOulineVisible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath.isoutlinevisible) to determine whether the mouse pointer is over the outline of a shape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let assume that your line is inside a panel called myPanel. Then you need the following methods:

```
private void MyPanel_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (IsShapeContainingMouse(e.Location))
    {
        Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Hand;
    }
    else
    {
        Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default;
    }
}

private bool IsShapeContainingMouse(Point location)
{
    Point shapeStartPosition = GetShapeStartPosition();
    Point shapeEndPosition = GetShapeEndPosition();
    return shapeStartPosition.X <= location.X && location.X <= shapeEndPosition.X && shapeStartPosition.Y <= location.Y && location.Y <= shapeEndPosition.Y;
 }
}
```

You need to implement both methods `GetShapeStartPosition()` and `GetShapeStartPosition()` to get the start and the end of the line.